# PureCSS menu dropdown elements go off page

Tags: html, css, html-lists

How do I stop the right menu dropdown child elements from going off the page? I know it is simple but don't know the CSS to change to get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Your page title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
    <style>
        ul{background-color: #4CAF50; width: 100%}

    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal">
    <ul class="pure-menu-list">
        <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-selected"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Home</a></li>

        <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-has-children pure-menu-allow-hover">
            <a href="#" id="menuLink1" class="pure-menu-link">Contact</a>
            <ul class="pure-menu-children">
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Email</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Twitter</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Tumblr Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-has-children pure-menu-allow-hover" style="float:right">
            <a href="#" id="menuLink2" class="pure-menu-link">Test</a>
            <ul class="pure-menu-children">
                <li class="pure-menu-item""><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Email</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Twitter</a></li>
                <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Tumblr Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>


    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to have them so the start at the right hand side of the page but not go off.

thanks

Comment: You have a typo in your code: `<li class="pure-menu-item"">` has two double quotes at the end of the class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some tweaking and adding in your CSS, you can achieve this. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ys1Leffg/), I also cleaned your code.

Add the class `.right-menu` to the most right menu to get this working.

```
.pure-menu-horizontal .right-menu .pure-menu-children {
  left: auto; /* Position from right, not from left */
  right: 0; /* Position from right, not from left */
}
```

*Update*

I used `display: flex;` to address [the problem that Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=488725)'s having to properly show the menu you wanted.

This is what you need to add:

```
.pure-menu-horizontal .pure-menu-list.pure-menu-list {
  display: flex;
}

.pure-menu-horizontal .right-menu {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

See [my updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sb2arazf/). Read more about the *handy* `flexbox` property at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Comment: Hi, that solution works in IE but goes onto the next line down on Firefox... any ideas on how to solve that?

Comment: @user2229747 That's a Firefox bug, addressed here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=488725 I will update my answer with a working solution for Firefox as well.